# nginx + proxy pas - 504 gateway timeout , timeout after 1min, 30 sec. Tried proxy_read_timeout but no luck

Tags: php, django, nginx, webserver

here is my config :

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8003/;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
    send_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
}
```

But, I am getting 504 Gateway Timeout error after 1min 30 seconds . But not according to my above configurations, whats the reason ?
How can i make it work for more seconds .

Comment: may be you miss proxy_send_timeout see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_send_timeout and http://www.nginxtips.com/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/

Comment: That's a valid answer, @user1653509

Answer (score 3):

I know OP has probably long moved on from this question, but the timeout settings should be in the `server` or `http` block *not* in the `location` block. Example:

```
server {
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
    send_timeout 3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600s;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8003/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IN CASE** there's a NAT gateway between your NGINX instance & the destination (proxy_pass), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351959/9956279) may help.