# 504 Gateway Time out with every PUT request

Tags: php, apache, nginx, put, http-status-code-504

On one of our staging/testing server (ngnix/apache config tried with both) for every PUT request to Php Laravel app, i'm getting 504 Gateway Time-out while the rest of the requests are working correctly. When testing locally there are no errors. No modification were made to the code and it was working just fine few weeks ago.

Interestingly PUT request is working just fine for my teammates. is it something to do with my ISP OR something is wrong at our staging server ?

NOTE: PUT request is working just fine for me at our Production server (ngnix config)

Comment: Same configuration for production and testing servers?

Comment: yes kind of same configuration but not totally same, at Production we have auto-scaling enabled but we are using nginx at both staging and production.

Comment: Did you try to increase timeout values for testing server? : https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/. May be this one is less powerfull and take too much time to respond to specific queries.

Comment: yes tried that too, but why it's working just fine for others? that is weird !

Comment: Header issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36589120/2269979