# upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream laravel forge nigix

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, proxy, laravel-forge

Hi i am working on a laravel 5.4 project it calls the amazon api the script take longer then 2 to 3 minutes the script works fine on local appache server. but when i shifted my code to laravel forge by creating a digitOccean server and then i am running the amazon api call it gives me this error 504 Gateway Time-out

The server didn't respond in time.

i have checked the logs it says this in the nigix error log file

> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response
>   header from upstream

i have tried adding

```
 proxy_read_timeout 1500;
```

and also

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 1500;
```

but the issue is still their

here is my nigix config file from laravel forge

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/datadrive.nl/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name datadrive.nl;
    root /home/forge/datadrive.nl/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    # ssl_certificate;
    # ssl_certificate_key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/datadrive.nl/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        proxy_read_timeout 1500;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/datadrive.nl-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1500;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/datadrive.nl/after/*;
```

what i want is this that the my php script does not timeout if it takes even 5 to 6 minutes to execute..

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453388/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-504-gateway-timeout/36589120#36589120

Comment: okay i will try..