# Active Storage problems uplod and download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger, rails-activestorage

I got activestorage to work with my rails 5.2 app on localhost.

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
```

I'm using direct-upload and storing to local storage. But when I deploy to the staging server I hit two problems:

**Upload is broken**

Of the three HTTP requests needed to upload a file:

1. POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads HTTP/1.1
2. PUT /rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMi...3aff HTTP/1.1
3. POST /course/1908/file_update HTTP/1.1

the second request never get's a response. The response should be a simple 204 No Content, but instead it runs into a timeout.

the server setup is:

1. nginx revers proxy on on machine calls
2. apache on another machine, which runs
3. passenger

I can see in the logfile that rails writes that the response for the second
request is actually quite fast:

```
Started PUT "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMi...
...
Disk Storage (0.8ms) Uploaded file to key: 82L8qxveeux.. (checksum: ..J1BK==)
Completed 204 No Content in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Download is broken**

When I attache a file to a course via the rails console, and then
try to download the file, I recieve an empty file with the right filename.

Again, the rails logfile seems ok:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOn....
...
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

but somewhere between nginx, apache and passenger the body of the response is lost.

Any ideas what could be at fault here?

Answer (score 1):

**Upload is broken**

found no explanation but a solution at [Nginx reverse proxy causing 504 Gateway Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453388/nginx-reverse-proxy-causing-504-gateway-timeout/36589120#36589120)

replace

```
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

with

```
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

and the timeout goes away,  uploading files works.

**Download is broken**

I found an unexptected Heder in the HTTP response, containing the path of the uploaded file in local storage:

```
X-Sendfile: /var/www/.../storage/Rj/9o/Rj9oZL9W1jsHrnS7YJyw5
```

googling X-Sendfile I found an apache module

```
https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/
```

that takes this Response header and the send the file as the response body.
you can install it on ubuntu / debian with

```
apt install libapache2-mod-xsendfile
```

and configure it in apache:

```
XSendFile On
XSendFilePath /var/www/virthosts....
```

It seems activestorage uses this by default, but it's
not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.